# Given N sets and all pairs of non-empty intersections between those sets, can those N sets be real number intervals?

Tags: proof-verification, problem-solving, computational-complexity

> Thanks to @LordSharkOfTheUnknown, I now realize that I wish to recognize if a graph is an interval graph. He had linked this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph) of the subject, but I have not understood the recognition algorithm described there

I was solving a question in Stack Overflow in Portuguese about a particular problem that could be modeled as graph-colouring. The problem was something like this:

> I have `n` machines. Those machines needs to work at continuous intervals: `I_1` for the first machine, `I_2` for the second and so on. Each machine needs one operator to work properly, and each operator can only handle a single machine at a given time. What is the minimum number of operators needed?

So, I have modeled this as a graph:

- each vertex `k` is a machine `k`/time interval `I_k`
- each edge connecting vertex `j` and `k` is a time overlap between intervals `I_j` and `I_k`; or equaly it is a non-empty intersection between `I_j` and `I_k`
- each vertex colour is an operator, so no operator can operate two similtaneous machines, thus one colour cannot be it's own neighbor

So far, everything is fine. But, given a graph, can it have the semantics above? This can also be asked as the title question:

- Given `n` sets and a list of all pairs of sets that has non-empty intersections, can all of those sets be continuous intervals of real numbers?

So far, I know that this problem lies in NP, because if I have a list of intervals for each set, than I can test if all the intersections apply and validate if is a correct input.

---

For example, a valid input:

Given 4 sets (A,B,C,D) with the following intersections:

- A,B
- B,C
- C,D
- A,D
- B,D

It is a valid graph. Because I can have this values:

- A = [1,10]
- B = [8,15]
- D = [8,14]
- C = [12,18]

All the intersections above occurs, thus these intervals represents a valid input

---

For example, an invalid input:

Given 4 sets (A,B,C,D) with the following intersections:

- A,B
- B,C
- C,D
- A,D

There are no such values for A, B, C and D so that they are continuous intervals ou real numbers and there exista only those 4 non-empty intersections

---

- Original question that I was solving: [Escalonamento de máquinas - Teoria dos Grafos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219143/64969)
- SOpt question of this same open question: [Como identificar um grafo inválido para problema de alocação de operadores por máquina?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257864/64969)

Comment: These are *interval graphs*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown great! Thanks for the link, it is a new concept to me. I wish to recognize if a graph is an interval graph, but didn't understand that Wikipedia algorithm